# ¿Cómo usar más de un tooltip en C#?

Tags: c#, diseño, tooltip

Tengo algunos controles que contienen dos tooltips: uno que se debería mostrar al dejar el mouse sobre él, explicando para qué sirve, y otro que es una advertencia que debe aparecer cuando el usuario deje un espacio en blanco o algo así.

Sin embargo, el tooltip de advertencia aparece al dejar el mouse sobre el control y el otro no aparece nunca (Y deja de aparecer en otros controles que no tienen el de advertencia)

Esa es mi pregunta: ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de añadirlos para que aparezcan como debe?

Como ejemplo tengo esto:

Este es el código del tooltip de información

```
// tooltips
this.tooltips.ToolTipIcon = System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon.Info;
this.tooltips.ToolTipTitle = "How to use";
```

Este es el de advertencias:

```
// warnings
this.warnings.IsBalloon = true;
this.warnings.ToolTipIcon = System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon.Warning;
this.warnings.ToolTipTitle = "Warning";
```

Y, por ejemplo, este es un ComboBox que tiene estos dos (Solo lo importante)

```
this.warnings.SetToolTip(this.cipher_comboBox, "You have to select an element");
this.tooltips.SetToolTip(this.cipher_comboBox, "Select an element");
```

También he tratado de intercambiar las líneas pero no pasa nada

En cierto momento, si no se ha seleccionado un elemento, quiero que aparezca el tooltip de advertencias, había hecho esto

```
warnings.Show(warnings.GetToolTip(cipher_comboBox), cipher_comboBox, 5000);
```

Pero tampoco resulta

Comment: ¿Puedes ampliar tu pregunta con el código como lo tienes? De esa forma podremos ver dónde falla.

Comment: Listo, he añadido los trozos de código

Comment: *Y, por ejemplo, este es un ComboBox que tiene estos dos (Solo lo importante)* Tu código muestra dos tooltips asignados a dos variables diferentes.

Comment: Sí, uno es el de instrucciones y otro el de advertencias, tienen estilos diferentes, de ahí que mi pregunta sea que como tener dos en un solo control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el hecho de asignar consecutivamente el tooltip no redunda en que el control sepa que tiene asociado dos elementos tooltip.

```
this.warnings.SetToolTip(this.cipher_comboBox, "You have to select an element");
this.tooltips.SetToolTip(this.cipher_comboBox, "Select an element");
```

La solución que yo le doy a esto es que si quiero mostrar un tooltip de info cuando obtengo el foco del control por ejemplo, haría así:

```
private void ComboBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Ocultamos por si hay un tooltip previo.
    warnings.Hide(comboBox1);
    // Configuramos el tooltip (esto se puede hacer al inicio)
    tooltips.ToolTipTitle = "How to Use";
    tooltips.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
    // Asociamos el tooltip al control
    tooltips.SetToolTip(comboBox1, "Select an element");
    // Forzamos a que se muestre
    tooltips.Show("Select an element", comboBox1);
}
```

Luego para cuando el control pierda el foco podemos hacer que se muestre el otro tooltip:

```
private void ComboBox1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Ocultamos por si hay un tooltip previo.
    tooltips.Hide(comboBox1);
    // Configuramos el tooltip (esto se puede hacer al inicio)
    warnings.ToolTipTitle = "Warning!";
    warnings.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
    // Asociamos el tooltip al control
    warnings.SetToolTip(comboBox1, "You have to select an element");
    // Forzamos a que se muestre
    warnings.Show("You have to select an element", comboBox1);
}
```

Comment: Gracias! No quería tener que hacer una validación así para mantener el programa lo más óptimo posible, pero veo que será necesario hacerlo. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Tengo un ejemplo de un tooltip en xaml... Esta en uwp pero posiblemente sea aplicable a wpf y/o xamarin con obviamente algunas modificaciones.

```
<Button Name="PrintButton" 
                Content="&#xE2F6;" 
                Style="{StaticResource EstiloButton}" 
                RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                Margin="0,0,8,0"
                Click="PrintButton_OnClick">
            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip Placement="Mouse" Background="#003366">
                    <TextBlock Text="Imprimir" Foreground="White"/>
                </ToolTip>
            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        </Button>
```

Respecto a que provoca el tooltip y el contenido lo puedes bindear probablemente a tu gusto. Espero te sirva, saludos!